# Permutations and combinations in R

Tags: r, combinations, permutation, combinatorics

I have `N=4` elements and `q=3` elements symboled as `1`,`2`,`3`.

I create the matrix `M`, which contains all the vectors of `N=4` elements with `2` elements equal to `1`, `1` element equals to `2` and `1` element equals to `3` in all possible positions, using `interpc` as follows:

```
library(iterpc)
I=iterpc(c(2,1,1), labels=c(1,2,3), ordered=TRUE)
M=getall(I)
> M
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    1    2    3
 [2,]    1    1    3    2
 [3,]    1    2    1    3
 [4,]    1    2    3    1
 [5,]    1    3    1    2
 [6,]    1    3    2    1
 [7,]    2    1    1    3
 [8,]    2    1    3    1
 [9,]    2    3    1    1
 [10,]    3    1    1    2
 [11,]    3    1    2    1
 [12,]    3    2    1    1
```

I want a way in order to NOT create the rows `2`, `5`, `6`, `10`, `11` and `12`.

These rows are connected with the others. For example, row `2` can be constructed by permutting the elements `2` and `3` of row `1`. In the same way row `5` can be constructed using row `3`.

So, is there any way just to construct the rows `1`, `3`, `4`, `7`, `8` and `9`, but NOT the rows `2`, `5`, `6`, `10`, `11` and `12` ?

Comment: why is row 8 kept?

Comment: @MelissaKey I corrected my answer. I keep row 8, because with this one I can create the row 11. So, it is the same if I keep row 8 or row 11.

Comment: please include the library call(s)

Comment: You need to be clear about your rules for saying two rows are "connected."

Comment: It should be noted that `iterpc` is no longer maintained and users are encouraged to switch to `arrangements`. See [this link](https://cran.r-project.org/package=iterpc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to treat your 2s and 3s equivalently for permutations. Here's a solution that just uses 1s and 3s for the initial generation, and then goes through each row changing the first 3 to a 2:

```
library(iterpc)
I=iterpc(c(2,2), labels=c(1,3), ordered=TRUE)
M=getall(I)
t(apply(M, 1, function(x) {x[match(3, x)] = 2; x}))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    1    2    3
# [2,]    1    2    1    3
# [3,]    1    2    3    1
# [4,]    2    1    1    3
# [5,]    2    1    3    1
# [6,]    2    3    1    1
```

Comment: incredible insight!!! This has me wondering how this can be extended to the general case.